# Count the execution times of bolt and spout in Storm

Tags: apache-storm

Now there is a problem that puzzles me. How should I count the execution times of bolt and spout in Storm? I have tried to use ConcurrentHashmap (considering multithreading), but it can't be done on multiple machines. Can you help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Considering your question i think you are trying to keep a track of number of tuple got executed and not the amount of time bolt or spout takes to execute one tuple.
You can use metices with graphite for visualisation. It gives a time series data.
Database can also be used for the same purpose.

Comment: I need to count the number of bolt executions every time the topology is running, and I need to judge the number of times and do some processing. The number of execution times of each topology is not the same, so it is inappropriate to use the database here, and the database persists the data. If you use a database, you need to initialize the data every time you execute the topology, but it's not feasible, and I've tried it. I hope you can understand what I said, and maybe I'm not very clear about it.

Comment: I need to count the number of bolt executions every time the topology is running : Please make it clear.